# what's wrong in this RSA why the results of encryption/decryption are different?

Tags: vb.net

`enter code here`this is p,q,n,phi,e,d and there is no any error in code and all the arthimitic operations are correct and I am sure, but what probably I mistake here?

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  'encrypt
    ee = Convert.ToDouble(txtE.Text)
    n = Convert.ToDouble(txtN.Text)
    m = Convert.ToDouble(txtMessage.Text)

    txtCipher.Text = powermod(m, ee, n)
End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 'decrypt
    dd = Convert.ToDouble(txtD.Text)
    n = Convert.ToDouble(txtN.Text)
    c = Convert.ToDouble(txtCipher.Text)

    txtMessageRecovery.Text = powermod(c, dd, n)
```

End Sub

```
Public Function powermod(base As Double, exponent As Double, modulus As Double) As Double
    If base < 1 Or exponent < 0 Or modulus < 1 Then Return -1
    Dim result As Double = 1
    While (exponent > 0)
        If ((exponent Mod 2) = 1) Then
            result = (result * base) Mod modulus
        End If
        base = (base * base) Mod modulus
        exponent = Floor(exponent / 2)
    End While
    Return result
End Function
```

[the numbers in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B7Px.jpg)

Comment: The *double* type is not accurate enough to do this correctly, integer math is required.  Use the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Comment: thanks hans, but what's mean by integer math?, do you mean Integer data type? @HansPassant

Comment: Consider googling "floating point math vs integer math" to find stuff to help you understand the difference.

Comment: @HansPassant I use double because it doesn't have maximum range

Comment: It trades range for precision.  Double has only 53 bits to represent the value, the simplest RSA encryption key needs 330 bits.  System.Security.Cryptograph has the code that can manipulate that many bits.